# Backup catching for exception thrown in EventHandler

Tags: c#, exception, event-handling, windows-services

I have a C# Program running as a Windows service doing some Network shenanigans
I thought I had last-ditch "Log Fatal Errors" handling set up. But I've come across an edge case where the Service ends up dead but dodges those catches. :(

I believe this is caused by code throwing an Exception in the EventHandler registered to a .NET library's event.

Obviously I can (and**should**!) catch the Exception in my handler, but I'd like to understand how this is avoiding my fall-back error handling, and whether I can add some even more robust fall back logging, to ensure that I have some log records to analyse similar silent bugs in future.

---

The punchline of relevant code isn't terribly complex:

`ServiceBase.Run(container.Resolve<MyProjectWindowsService>());` in a `try ...catch` in `Program.Main()`
`MyProjectWindowsService : ServiceBase` is the service object with an `OnStop()` implmentation.
`NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += CodeThatThrows;`

But when that Exception is thrown, neither `OnStop()` nor the `try...catch` trigger.
I can get it in a debugger, and it doesn't seem to **go** anywhere .. it just ... stops.

Fuller program details below, if you want them.

**How can I catch and log unhandled exceptions in Event Handlers registered to external library events?**

*(Also ... Is the behaviour I've described above the **expected** behaviour, or is there something slightly weird happening?)*

---

Program EXE entry point:

```cs
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.NLog;
using NLog;

namespace MyProject.Service
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        /// <summary>
        ///     The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                // var container = ...DI Setup...
                ServiceBase.Run(container.Resolve<MyProjectWindowsService>());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex, "Unexpected error");
            }
            finally
            {
                Logger.Info("==========================");
                Logger.Info("WindowsService Stopped (2)");
                Logger.Info("==========================");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Service Object

```cs
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Wcf;
using NLog;

namespace MyProject.Service
{
    public class MyProjectWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public DNSProxyWindowsService(ILogger logger)
        {
            ServiceName = Constants.SERVICE_NAME;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _logger.Info("==============================");
            _logger.Info("DNProxy WindowsService Started");
            _logger.Info("==============================");

            //Other Active setupsteps
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                //Other Active shutdown steps.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex, "Could not shut down service tidily");
            }
            finally
            {
                _logger.Info("==========================");
                _logger.Info("WindowsService Stopped (1)");
                _logger.Info("==========================");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EventListener Registered to and ultimately invoked:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using NLog;
using Exception = System.Exception;

namespace DNSProxy.Service
{

    public class NetworkService
    {
        public NetworkService()
        {
        }

        public bool NetworkDetectionEnabled
        {
            set
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged;
                    NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += OnNetworkAddressChanged;
                }
                else
                {
                    NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged -= OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged;
                    NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged -= OnNetworkAddressChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnNetworkAddressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CodeThatCanApparentlyThrow();
        }

        private void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
        {
            CodeThatCanApparentlyThrow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To repeat ... I'm aware that the correct solution for this bug is to fix the Exception thrown from the EventHandler, but identifying what happened in this case was hard due ot the lack of any log details, so I want to protect myself against future hard-to-diagnose-bugs!

Comment: Potentially something could using async somewhere and not observed the exception in your handler? That is just pure speculation, but it is a way in which an exception can be thrown in code that appears to executing in a try block, but due to no awaiting tasks or something similar, execution leaves the try block and the exception bubbles out later

Comment: Probably your event handlers are running in the separate thread, that's why you miss the exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unfortunately can only speculate why the exception isn't being caught by your code (and I've kept that speculation to the comments)

However 2 events that might help you are,

**AppDomain.UnhandledException** - this allows you to register a global handler for any unhandled exceptions in your application. Here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.8

**TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException** - I've included this as I'm not familiar with the internals of the framework libraries you are using, but there maybe some asynchronous code happening somewhere, that is potentially not observing the result of a task. If a faulted task (ie an exception was thrown) is never awaited or never has the Result property accessed and then goes out of scope so it can be garbage collected; at some indeterminate point in the future, it will get collected and an UnobservedTaskException will get thrown. Subscribing to this event, will let you handle that scenario. Documentation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `AppDomain.UnhandledException` won't catch exceptions other than thrown in main thread. And also `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` may not help since i had a simple sample which wasn't working. But there is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` almost catches everything.

Comment: @Eldar the documentation appears to disagree 
"If the UnhandledException event is handled in the default application domain, it is raised there for any unhandled exception in any thread, no matter what application domain the thread started in"

Comment: `AppDomain.UnhandledException` sorted it. Though adding the Task one also sounds smart.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit dig out what catches what on a WPF application :

```
 var domain  = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
 domain.UnhandledException += (o, args) =>
                                         {
                                             Debug.WriteLine("Catched in UnhandledException");
                                             Debug.WriteLine(args.ExceptionObject);
                                         };

  domain.FirstChanceException += (o, args) =>
                                           {
                                               Debug.WriteLine("Catched in FirstChanceException");
                                               Debug.WriteLine(args.Exception);
                                           };

TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (o, args) =>
                                                     {
                                                         Debug.WriteLine("Catched in UnobservedTaskException");
                                                         Debug.WriteLine(args.Exception);
                                                     };
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                                  {
                                      Debug.WriteLine("Workinf");
                                      await Task.Delay(1000);
                                      try
                                      {
                                          throw new Exception("oops");
                                      }
                                      catch (Exception exception)
                                      {

                                          throw new Exception("oopps catched", exception);
                                      }
                                  });
```

The output will be :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in WpfApp1.exe
Catched in FirstChanceException
System.Exception: oops
   at ....
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in WpfApp1.exe
Catched in FirstChanceException
System.Exception: oopps catched ---> System.Exception: oops
   at ...
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ...
```

So `FirstChanceException` will be catching everything (even the handled ones) and the rest won't be catching anything. My suggestion is modifying your example like this:

```
public class NetworkService
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext currContext;
        public NetworkService()
        {
            this.currContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }

        private void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CodeThatCanApparentlyThrow();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.currContext.Post(s => throw exception, null); // this will propagate your exception into main thread
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest re-running your test without a `FirstChanceHandler` registered. I suspect you may see different behaviour? Perhaps, because the FirstChance Handler causes everything else to be considered "Handled"?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica--Brondahl-- already tried and they are not catching. I will try it with a console application too, may be STA ApatmentState causing them to fail to catch

Comment: Interesting... well I can confirm that AD.UhE is triggered by EventHandlers for a WinService :)